# Who wins the Even/Odd game, and by how much?

Tags: real-numbers, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

The Even/Odd game is defined as follows:

Both players pick a number in $(0,1]$ for positive $y$. Even's number is called $E$. Odd's number is called $O$. The scorer number is $\Big \lceil \dfrac{E+y+1}{O+y} \Big\rceil$. If it is even, Even gets a point. If it is odd, Odd gets a point. I conjecture that Even would be winning in the long run. What is the expected value for each player, assuming perfect play for a given $y?$ How does the behavior of perfect players change with different values of $y?$ There is no Nash equilibrium for $y = 1.$

Comment: How do you define _even_ and _odd_ in $(0, 1]$?

Comment: This is not clear at all. Please edit for clarity.  Perhaps it would help if you wrote out a few rounds of some explicit instance of the game.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer If one computes the ceiling of $(E+1)/O$ one gets an integer. That is either even or odd, and post explains who wins depending on that.

Comment: @coffeemath Ah ok, I thought the "it" referred to the original number chosen.

Comment: This game seems like it might not have an equilibrium, so I am editing it.

Comment: Why is the interval defined that way instead of the more straightforward $(y,y+1]$?

Comment: Originally this game was defined based on the interval $(0,1].$ It isn't clear whether the outcomes when played on $(1/x,(x+1)/x]$ would depend on the value of $x.$

Comment: @GregMartin The reason why I put it this way is to prevent the behavior from getting chaotic at a finite value.

Comment: @ExtraSuperman But your interval is the same as G.Martin's if one defines his $y$ as your $1/x.$ So I don't see what you're saying about behavior getting chaotic.

Comment: @coffeemath With G. Martin's scheme, it becomes chaotic near y = 0, whereas in my scheme, it never becomes chaotic for finite x.

Comment: @ExtraSuperman I don't get your last comment at all. Martin's $y,$ no matter how near zero, is yet positive. The corresponding $1/x$ for your version will still be finite, albeit it might be large. Either way a *specific* value of $y$ or $x$ must be chosen and known to both players before play begins, or the intervals are meaningless in the play of the game.

Comment: @coffeemath My question is about the behavior of the game and mathematicians usually do not use functions that are chaotic at a finite value. Therefore, I made the chaos be at infinity.

Comment: I mean, derivatives and integrals and other stuff like that would be possible without chaos at 0 but would still be possible with chaos at infinity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136812/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-extrasuperman).

Comment: For $x=1$ we will have $E+1 \in (2,3]$  Each player can guarantee a win if they can pick a number closer to the bottom end than the other.  I think it will become a contest of naming the smallest $\epsilon$ so they can pick $1+\epsilon$

Comment: @RossMillikan That means that there is no Nash equilibrium.